# Prevent login modal/popup form closing when there is validation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I prevent popup login form from closing after submitting it whenever there is a validation error? I'm using node.js and ejs as view engine.

Login html form:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__box">
    <form id="login-form" action="/auth/login" method="POST">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <% errors.forEach(function(message) { %>
        <div class="alert alert__danger">
          <p><%= message %></p>
        </div>
      <% }) %>
      <input type="email" placeholder="email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="password">
      <button id="modal-submit" class="btn">Login</button>
      <span class="modal__close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Frontend JS code:

```
class Nav {
  constructor(){
    this.modalBtn = document.querySelector('.modal__btn')
    this.modalBg = document.querySelector('.modal')
    this.modalCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.modal__close')
    this.events()
  }

  events() {
    this.modalBtn.addEventListener('click', () => this.modalOpen())

    this.modalCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => this.modalClose())
  }

  modalOpen() {
    this.modalBg.classList.add('active')
  }

  modalClose() {
    this.modalBg.classList.remove('active')
  }
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: Use ajax instead if form action.

Comment: Are you using backend validation? If you are using frontend validation only then you can use preventDefault() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using backend validation in Node you can use AJAX request instead if "form action". If you are implementing validation in frontend then just use preventDefault() on form "submit" event.

```js
//USING AJAX

$.ajax({
  url: '/auth/login',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    username: "input filed value here",
    password: "input filed value here"
  },
  success: data => {

    //if login successful close the modal using JS or jQuery.
    // maybe redirect to some other page


    //if login failed show error on your modal using JS or jQuery
  },
  //if you are using Express Validator or some other error middleware in server side you may want this
  error: error => {
    //do something with "error" object
    //show error on your modal using JS or jQuery
  }
})
```